# Nagios Alert - Server Down but Server is online

Tags: nagios

Receiving Nagios Server Down Alerts but this is not the case. Server is online.
All other server alerts are working correctly, only difference is this server is receiving a DHCP address which I don't believe makes any difference.

I pinged the servers and latency is not the issue. I can ping the nagios server and the nagios server is able to ping the server. Any suggestions of what I can look at, I am out of ideas. Nagios Configuration is below, I don't see how it can be wrong as I copied it from server and simply changed the server name.

```
define host{
        use                     windows-server           
        host_name               cielo01
        alias                   cielo01
        address                 cielo01
        }

define service{
        use                             local-service    
        host_name                       cielo01
        service_description             PING
    check_command           check_ping!500.0,20%!1000.0,60%
        }

define service{
        use                             local-service  
        host_name                       cielo01
        service_description             Disk Space on C
    check_command           check_disk_smb!C$!85!95
        }
```

Comment: This question might be a better fit with ServerFault. They suggest that if you dont use the IP address that you use the FQDN to prevent ambiguity. Silly question but you get a response from the correct server yes? Also are the pings within the thresholds you set?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I will try FQDN. Not a silly question as I have made many silly mistakes but yes the ping response is to the correct server and lantency is ~67MS so we shouldn't get these alerts.

Comment: Seems that adding it FQDN fixed it. Strange it would make a difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the object definition descrition for `address` from the [documentation](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html) it says the following:

> You can use a FQDN to identify the host instead of an IP address, but
>   if DNS services are not available this could cause problems.

Have you tried using the FQDN?